# What is the simplest way to rotate a div smooth?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, rotation, transition

What is the best way to make a div rotate on click, but with a transition?

I tried this but it only makes a smooth transition when class is added but not when class is removed :

js :

```
$('#firstDiv' + id).click(function(){
    $("#Img" + id).toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

css :

```css
.rotated { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to rotate when the class is removed??

Comment: You can now use rotate as a property. `rotate: -90deg`. Also I think the transition should exist on the element without the `.rotated` class.

Comment: @silencedogood It does rotate when the class is removed, but it rotates instantly

Comment: @Axel Please take a look at my answer that let you the possibilily to toggle the rotation animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transition` css property should stay on the element.

`transition` property is what makes makes the rotation look smooth. When it's on the class which is doing the rotation and you remove the class, even the `transition` property gets removed. Hence the rotation end is not smooth.

Your logic is right but use may be a different class to apply `-webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;` or apply directly on the element. Make sure it is not removed when you remove `rotated` class.

```js
const myDiv = $('#my-div');

setTimeout(()=>{
  myDiv.addClass('rotated');
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.rotated { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='my-div'>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a working example. It was more self explanatory even without a demo but still..

Comment: @vatz88 `Added a working example` of what ? There's not even the inital method `.toggleClass()` in your example :/

Comment: @johannchopin It doesn't have to be exact replica as in the question. The correct use of `transition` is very well conveyed. I wanted to make a minimal working example.

Comment: @vatz88 Just take a look to this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5Lt08pm/3/) that use your example. You will see that when the class `rotated` is removed during the animation it not go to the initial state with a **smooth transition**. But that's actually the question -> `but not when class is removed` !

Comment: @johannchopin I see it's smooth both ways. If you have any genuine question regarding code or implementation, please ask that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `transition-duration` property on the target :

```js
$('#firstDiv').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

```css
#firstDiv {
  width: fit-content;
  transition-duration: 2s;  /* <-- Provide a smooth animation from 2s on all 'changes'*/
}

.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="firstDiv">
  test
</div>
```